# How to create and read pkcs7 signed envelop with smime format?

Tags: c++, c, openssl

I want to create pkcs7 signed envelop having S/MIME format and also want to read it. The file extension is `pk7`.

How to do it with the OpenSSL library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`SMIME_read_PKCS7()`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/SMIME_read_PKCS7.html) and [`SMIME_write_PKCS7()`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/SMIME_write_PKCS7.html) functions can be used to convert an SMIME message into a PKCS7 structure and vice-versa.

You can use [`PKCS7_sign()`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/PKCS7_sign.html#) / [`PKCS7_encrypt()`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/PKCS7_encrypt.html#) to create PKCS7 structures, and [`PKCS7_verify()`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/PKCS7_verify.html#) / [`PKCS7_decrypt()`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/PKCS7_decrypt.html#) to consume them.